# Drag feature openLayers

Tags: javascript, json, vector, drag-and-drop, openlayers

I need your help to find the problem i can't drag my feauture, 
    however i use the same code on this link http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/drag-feature.html
    Thank you in advance ^^, after i have to find a way when i drag my feauture to another one i have to change the icon of the first one and deplace it at the first location i mean coordinates

```
        var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
        renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] :  
        OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers; 
        vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer", {
        renderers: renderer
        }); 
        //**********************************************

        map.addLayer(vectors);


        //****************************************************************************


        controls = {
                point: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors,
                OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
                line: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors,
                OpenLayers.Handler.Path),
                polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors,
                OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon),
                drag: new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(vectors)
            };
        for(var key in controls) {
                map.addControl(controls[key]);
        }
        document.getElementById('noneToggle').checked = true;



function toggleControl(element) {
                 for(key in controls) {
                 var control = controls[key];
                 if(element.value == key && element.checked) {
                     control.activate();
                 } else {
                     control.deactivate();
                 }
             }
         }

<div id="controls">
    <ul id="controlToggle">
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="none" id="noneToggle"
                   onclick="toggleControl(this);" checked="checked" />
            <label for="noneToggle">navigate</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="point" id="pointToggle" onclick="toggleControl(this);" />
            <label for="pointToggle">draw point</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="line" id="lineToggle" onclick="toggleControl(this);" />
            <label for="lineToggle">draw line</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="polygon" id="polygonToggle" onclick="toggleControl(this);" />
            <label for="polygonToggle">draw polygon</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="drag" id="dragToggle" onclick="toggleControl(this);" />
            <label for="dragToggle">drag feature</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put the code you have in jsFiddle as a full working example (or at lest the full html page). Copying part of the code from the working OpenLayers example will not help us debug your issue.

Comment: here is the link but I was not able to display the result
http://jsfiddle.net/q56NW/

Comment: You need to add openlayers.js as an external resource and turn on jquery, seeing as you are using it. However, there are still issues, but here is an updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/q56NW/1/

Comment: i have to add this bloc of javascript after (function($){

Comment: @JohnBarça do you have an idea how to add my own file script on jsfiddle

Comment: Put it on github and add to external sources?